# How to only display parent nodes with Kendo UI Treeview

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, treeview

I've looked at the documentation for the Treeview component and it does not seem to provide any out of the box functionality for what I need.

I have a tree that for example looks like this:

Root item

- Parent item

  - Child item
  - Child item
  - Child item
- Parent item

  - Child item
- Parent item

  - Child item
  - Child item

The "Root item" is always present in the tree. I wish to be able to collapse all items except the "Parent items", or more precisely, only show "Parent items" on a button click.

Looking at the generated HTML for the treeview there does not seem to be any way of identifying which items are below "Parent items".

I currently have:

```
$("#collapse").click(function() {
    treeview.collapse(".k-item");
});
```

However this will collapse everything including "Parent items". How can I be specific about which items get collapsed?

Comment: Can you show your HTML part?

Answer (score 0):

You can set initial expanded items in dataSource with property `expanded`:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: [
        { text:'root', expanded:true, items:[
            {text:'parent', expanded:false, items:
            [
                {text:'child'}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]
});
```

Or you can collapse all nodes except first this way:

```
treeview.collapse('.k-item:not(:first)');
```